# How to make layouts show in below image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make this circle avatar in random position?
This my code.
I use stack inside container. Also use circle avatar inside stack and positioned widgets.

```
//main.dart
import 'package:application/start.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => Start(),
    },
  ));
}

//start.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Start extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartState createState() => _StartState();
}

class _StartState extends State<Start> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(
          5,
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                // color: Colors.purple,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 30,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      top: 10,
                      left: 50,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's work for make layout like show in image
[image]

Comment: Please describe what you *can* do and what *exactly* you are stuck with. Can you present a circle avatar? Can you generate random numbers? Can you position an element absolutely?

Comment: I want layout code for that shown in image( https://i.stack.imgur.com/71bpo.jpg).

Comment: I know what you want. Please tell us how far you got when you tried doing it so we can help you with the *specific* problem you are having.

Comment: I use container widget. Inside container i use circle avatar. But how i do each circle avatar place at position that shown in image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Random](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-math/Random-class.html) from `dart:math` to generate random numbers. Then you can use the [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget to find out how much room you have. Finally, you can use the [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget to position widgets exactly where you want them, in this case at your random coordinates.

Please note that I don't know the purpose of your randomness. You may want to make this a [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and keep your random numbers between calls to `build` so when your state of the app changes, your random avatars stay where they are. Or maybe not. It's your choice.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final random = Random();
  final avatarSize = 50.0;
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Stack(
        children:[
          new Positioned(
            left: avatarSize + (constraints.biggest.width - 2 * avatarSize ) / 100.0 * random.nextInt(100),
            top: avatarSize + (constraints.biggest.height - 2 * avatarSize ) / 100.0 * random.nextInt(100),
            child: new CircleAvatar(
              radius: avatarSize / 2,
              child: new Text('1'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            )
        ),
        new Positioned(
          left: avatarSize + (constraints.biggest.width - 2 * avatarSize ) / 100.0 * random.nextInt(100),
          top: avatarSize + (constraints.biggest.height - 2 * avatarSize ) / 100.0 * random.nextInt(100),
          child: new CircleAvatar(
            radius: avatarSize / 2,
            child: new Text('2'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          )
        ),
        new Positioned(
          left: avatarSize + (constraints.biggest.width - 2 * avatarSize ) / 100.0 * random.nextInt(100),
          top: avatarSize + (constraints.biggest.height - 2 * avatarSize ) / 100.0 * random.nextInt(100),
          child: new CircleAvatar(
            radius: avatarSize / 2,
            child: new Text('3'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          )
        ),
      ]);
  }));
  }
}
```